# Deploying IE Proxy settings to the NT Authority\System account using GPO

Tags: proxy, system, account, authority, nt

I am dealing with an interesting issue.  I am using AWS SSM to manage my Windows Updates and going through a 3rd party proxy server (which I have no control over, nor a choice to use it).  I am attempting to automate proxy settings (found here:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=782297) using GPO or any other method (.ps1, .cmd) available.  The only method I have found requires the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\PSTools> .\psexec -i -s -d cmd 
Then in the System User Context CMD prompt; 
C:\Windows\system32>whoami 
nt authority\system 
C:\Windows\system32>inetcpl.cpl 
Configure the settings manually according to the users internet 
connection settings.
```

I have been digging around and trying to use batch files, group policy preferences...and I am stumped.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Also, I have tried "[How to configure IE proxying for the local system account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250887/how-to-configure-ie-proxying-for-the-local-system-account)" already to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You're right there, you almost made it. Run Internet Explorer (`iexplore.exe`), not just `inetcpl.cpl`, under that user context, and configure the proxy inside Internet Explorer.